# What would happen if someone died while he/she is junub (in the state of janabah)?

Tags: sharia, ghusl, najis, judgements

He/she was junub as he was unsure whether he is impure or pure.

I just want to know what's the Islamic law or the shariah law behind this.

Please give only authentic answers which have evidences and proves from the Qur'an and/or hadith.

Jazak Allah hu khair

Comment: Did they purposely stay in the state of junub till they died or it was a mere coincidence? Because if it was a coincidence I doubt there will be a punishment!

Comment: @Aboudi what if he/she was not sure about it?

Comment: the reason I asked the question is to provide more details to those who may know the answer, however like I said if the intention is not to remain in a state of impurity then I doubt there will be a punishment! sorry I don't know the answer to this question!

Comment: I could have sworn that the question was about how many ghusul for someone who died in the state of janabah. what has happened?

Answer (score 1):

salam
I could only explain shia'view on dead human and his judgment about ablution.
there are two poits according to Ayatollah SISTANI'fatwa:

## first, it is necessary that we have to wash him or her with three kind of water namely Sedr,kafour and proper water.

## second, if some one died while he is junob it is necessary that washed by ablution belonged to dead not other ablutions such as ablution of Hayz or Jinabah.

I reported this fatwa from [here](http://www.sistani.org/persian/book/25103/4013/)

Comment: Yeah. it looks to be a right answer, since (at least) washing (ghusl) after his/her dead can be considered as substituing ... (AFAIK)

Comment: Sorry but what exactly is the difference between the janabah (being junub  جنب) and Jinabah? To me they are only two different transliterations of the same Arabic word  جنابة.